# How to Enable Logging to a Text file for the Entire job with sub jobs in it in Pentaho

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I am trying to store the logs of a Pentaho job that has 10 sub jobs and transformations inside it. I know i can do individually for each job and transformation by going into the settings and writing them to a text file. But i don't want too many files for each sub job. Is there a way that we can store the logs for single main job that captures all the sub jobs and transformation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Run the `kitchen`command with `-logfile` parameter.It will store the logs from all the jobs and transformation in the same file. Command example:

```
./kitchen.sh -file=/PRD/MasterJob.kjb -level=Minimal -logfile=/file/path/log.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you set the path and log_file name in parent job, it will generate log file for the entire flow. No need to mentioned it separately for sub jobs or transformations.